# How to extract specific values from XML file?

Tags: xml

```html
<LapRankIncludingDiscos>1</LapRankIncludingDiscos>
<Lap num="1" p="1" et="40.3468" s1="24.2085" s2="20.8324" s3="29.3612" fuel="0.969" twfl="0.996" twfr="0.996" twrl="0.996" twrr="0.996" fcompound="0,Michelin" rcompound="0,Michelin">74.4021</Lap>
<Lap num="2" p="1" et="114.7489" s1="19.2400" s2="20.9481" s3="29.2010" fuel="0.945" twfl="0.992" twfr="0.992" twrl="0.992" twrr="0.992" fcompound="0,Michelin" rcompound="0,Michelin">69.3891</Lap>
<Lap num="3" p="1" et="184.1380" s1="19.1381" s2="20.8024" s3="29.2390" fuel="0.918" twfl="0.988" twfr="0.992" twrl="0.988" twrr="0.988" fcompound="0,Michelin" rcompound="0,Michelin">69.1795</Lap>
<Lap num="4" p="1" et="253.3175" s1="19.2191" s2="20.6913" s3="29.1175" fuel="0.894" twfl="0.984" twfr="0.988" twrl="0.984" twrr="0.984" fcompound="0,Michelin" rcompound="0,Michelin">69.0280</Lap>
<Lap num="5" p="1" et="322.3455" s1="19.0733" s2="20.6675" s3="29.1936" fuel="0.867" twfl="0.976" twfr="0.984" twrl="0.980" twrr="0.980" fcompound="0,Michelin" rcompound="0,Michelin">68.9343</Lap>
<Lap num="6" p="1" et="391.2798" s1="19.1766" s2="20.8935" s3="29.4496" fuel="0.843" twfl="0.973" twfr="0.980" twrl="0.976" twrr="0.976" fcompound="0,Michelin" rcompound="0,Michelin">69.5196</Lap>
```

From this XML code, how do I get specific values from this XML file? for example I *only* want the value 0.996 from the twrr="0.996".

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to output all the values within the quotes of all twrr="_" . how do i do this?

Comment: In which language?

Comment: The XPath, `//Lap/@twrr`, will select all of the `twrr` attributes on `Lap` elements in the document.  XPath libraries are available in most languages.  Note that your shown XML is not well-formed, however, as XML documents must have a single root element.